# ASP .NET Core 3 + Identity Server issue with in-process and out-of-process hosting

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, identityserver4, asp.net-core-3.0

We're currently trying to upload two ASP .NET Core 3 simple web applications.

One is an IdentityServer4 application which generates tokens, while the other has some APIs endpoints, and relies on the first one for the authentication.

Our need is to publish them both under the same application pool where there are other applications, since we have an https certificate. We've already installed the asp net core 3 hosting kit.

Uploading just one, the authentication application, works fine. Uploading them both generates, when accessing the second, the error **500.35 ANCM Multiple In-Process Applications in same Process**. [This error's description is quite clear](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/aspnet/core/test/troubleshoot-azure-iis?view=aspnetcore-3.0) (seems like we can't host two in-process apps in the same pool), so we tried to configure both apps as OutOfProcess, by adding the following line to our .csproj files

```
<AspNetCoreHostingModel>OutOfProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
```

From what i read, this should interpose a Kestrel web server between our IIS and the caller. But now, for both of them, the error we get is **502.5 - ANCM Out-Of-Process Startup Failure**.

I've found no log anywhere, aside from the Window's event log, which reports this failure:

*Application '/LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT/XXXXX' with physical root 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\XXX\' failed to start process with commandline 'dotnet .\XXXXXXXXX.dll' with multiple retries. Failed to bind to port '10352'. First 30KB characters of captured stdout and stderr logs from multiple retries:*

and nothing more.

Any idea would be really appreciated at this point. :)

Thanks everybody and have a nice day.

Comment: Why do you need to use the same application pool for multiple applications though? If you use out-of-process hosting, each instance will spawn its own process anyway. What does a HTTPS certificate have to do with that?

Comment: A simple question first, why they must be in same pool?

Comment: @poke I've been told by our IT manager that having another application pool on IIS would mean having another subdomain with another HTTPS certificate to be bought and uploaded. Is he wrong?

Comment: So you want to host multiple applications on the same hostname/domain but with different virtual paths?

Comment: @poke Yep, the idea would be having something like: the first one in www.ourwebsite.com/authentication and the other in www.ourwebsite.com/api

Comment: OK, i made an application pool for each of those application and it's now working. No need for another subdomain and certificate. :) Thank you guys for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to an idea given by @poke and @Ygalbel, I questioned what i was told about the contraint of only one application pool for everything under the same domain, and made two different application pools. It's now working flawlessy. :)

Answer (score 0):

```xml
<aspNetCore 
  processPath="dotnet" 
  arguments=".\ISX_IQ.dll" 
  stdoutLogEnabled="false" 
  stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" 
  hostingModel="inprocess" />
```

[image]

Change `hostingModel` from `inprocess` to `OutOfprocess` in web.config

```xml
<aspNetCore 
   processPath="dotnet" 
   arguments=".\ISX_IQ.dll" 
   stdoutLogEnabled="false" 
   stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" 
   hostingModel="OutOfprocess" />
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).